# Why I'm getting Warning ! When i am adding button as a child <tr> using React Bootstrap Table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

[warning screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05om0.png)

I have tried to add a button as child of  but got this  error: " cannot appear as a child of " How can it be solved

````
              {products.map((product) => (
                <tr className="text-center p-0" key={product._id}>
                  <td className="w-0 p-0">{product?.name}</td>
                  <td>${product?.price}</td>
                  <td className="w-0 p-0 m-0">{product?.quantity}</td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(product._id)}
                    className="btn m-2 text-white"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                    <button
                      className="btn text-white"
                      style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
                    >
                      Update
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody> ```
````

Answer (score -1):

It's as the error says - your `<button` cannot be a child under `<tr`

`<tr>` or Table rows can only (typically) have `<td>`s as children (table cells; a button is not a table cell).

To fix this, Wrap the `button` as well as the `Link` in individual table cells.

```
<tr className="text-center p-0" key={product._id}>
                  <td className="w-0 p-0">{product?.name}</td>
                  <td>${product?.price}</td>
                  <td className="w-0 p-0 m-0">{product?.quantity}</td>
                  <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(product._id)}
                    className="btn m-2 text-white"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                    <button
                      className="btn text-white"
                      style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
                    >
                      Update
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```